# Continuous Power to Switched Outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Power source is supplied by 12/2 romex to switch.

Feed from switch to duplex outlet is supplied by 12/2 romex.

Is it possible to provide continuous power to one of the outlets while the other outlet remains switched?

Answer (score 3):

Not with the outlet on a spur with 12/2.

Worse, you cannot simply bypass the switch, unless there’s *another* light in the room under control of a switch.  Code requires every room must have a light switch in the usual location, and the switch must either operate a light, or a socket.

Answer (score 2):

You would need some 12/3 going from the switch to the outlet. You would need the neutral, which you have; you would need the switched hot, which you have but what you don't have is the always hot. that where the third wire comes in.

Are there any other wires in the outlet box?

Comment: Other than the ground, no.